# Sofrendo com php injection PHP Injection

Tags: php

Olá Pessoal estou sofrendo muito com php injection e acredito que a vulnerabilidade está nos códigos abaixo será que poderiam me ajudar a acabar com isso.

```
<?php $page = ($_GET['loadpage'] == "") ? "main" : stripslashes($_GET['loadpage']);
```

?>

```
<div id="centro">
    <?
        if(file_exists($page.".html")){
            include($page.".html");
        }else{
            echo '<div class="completo"><div class="inner_box" align="center">Página não encontrada</div></div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Willian, primeiramente, sempre utilize `Sanitize filters` do PHP para sanitizar as variáveis adquiridas por POST ou GET.

Referência: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Para resolver o problema de injections, você vai ter que mapear as entradas!
De modo simples, você pode fazer assim:

```
<?
    if(file_exists($page.".html")){
        if(in_array($page,array('pagina1','pagina2','pagina3'))){
             include($page.".html");
        } else {
             echo 'Você não tem permissão para acessar essa página';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Página não encontrada';
    }
?>
```

Entretanto, essas técnicas já estão consolidadas em diversos Frameworks PHP, sugiro que se for possível, você utilize um desses: CodeIgniter ou Laravel.

https://codeigniter.com

https://laravel.com

Comment: Wilson, Obrigado pelo retorno está parte consegui implementar porem no código ficou faltando fechar um parentese depois de 'pagina3' e o primeiro else tive que remover pois ficou dando erro na pagina.

Comment: Willian, qual erro está aparecendo?

Comment: Wilson, da que a pagina não pode ser exibida!

Answer (score -1):

Use as funções de `satanização` do próprio PHP:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php

Exemplo:

```php
<?php
$page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'loadpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL || FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
echo "Sua página: $page.\n";
?>
```

```html
<div id="centro">
    <?
        if(file_exists($page.".html")){
            include($page.".html");
        }else{
            echo '<div class="completo"><div class="inner_box" align="center">Página não encontrada</div></div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Nunca use os métodos/funções globais: $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER como você está fazendo, ao invés disso, use as funções de satanização, inclusive existem duas constantes que você pode passar no terceiro parâmetro, que é *FILTER_VALIDATE_URL* e *FILTER_SANITIZE_URL*.

Comment: Taffarel eu não entendi muito bem o uso dos filtros devo substituir o meu código por esse que colocou no exemplo?

Comment: Sim, você pode substituir. Aconselho-lhe ler a documentação de filtração do PHP.
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php